# How to set hostname of mysql url in kubernetes Spring application as evnironment variable?

Tags: mysql, spring, kubernetes

I have a spring application on kubernetes which connects to mysql database. This is my `spring-deployment.yml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spring
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spring
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: spring
        image: docker/spring
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8091
        env:
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
          value: jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.7:3306/buddyto_mstr_local?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
          value: root
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
          value: root
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: spring
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8091
      targetPort: 8091
  selector:
    app: sample-service
  type: NodePort
```

This value: `jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.7:3306/buddyto_mstr_local?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` contains the mysql pods IP adress which I got after running `kubectl get pods -o wide`

Every time I delete the mysql deployment and create a new one, a new IP address is assigned to the mysql deployment so I have to change it here from `172.17.0.7` to the new IP.

I want to set it in a way so that I don't have to keep changing the IP every time. What should I do for that?

Comment: You have to use the name not the IP

Comment: name of what? I can't use `localhost` because it doesn't work.
every deployment have different pod names and recreating one also changes the name.

Comment: the name of the service

Comment: ohh. I did not know this. I didn't even create a service for mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes creates DNS entries for your services so instead of using the IP use the service name.

Please read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even create a service for mysql. I didn't know about this.

Comment: Hi, sure! I am new to this website. How do I do that?

Comment: You should be able to click on a check mark on the left side of the answer

Comment: Done! Thank you once again.